# Why is one profile-page showing one rep, while another profile page is showing another rep for the same account?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, linked-accounts, association-bonus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

On my Stack Overflow profile page, the rep for my account on photography.stackexchange.com says 1. My actual rep however is 101, and when I look at my profile-page on Photography it says 101 (see images).

**As seen on Stack Overflow**
[image: As seen on Stack Overflow]

**As seen on Photography**
[image: As seen on Photography]

The account was created a couple of weeks ago, and I have had the rep since then, so I guess it isn't a cache-issue.

Not that it really matter, but does anyone know why this is?

**Update:** The same incorrect info is shown on the profile on both Meta and User Experience as well.

Comment: Same here. That's very weird. Can one of the mods do a whatever-you-call-it on the page?

Comment: We mods can do a "whatever-you-call-it" anywhere we want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought there was a bug report about this somewhere but I can't find it. Sometimes accounts with only an account association bonus take a lot longer to update. When I registered to Ask Ubuntu and never did anything there, it took around 2 weeks for it to update to 101 in the accounts list. It's currently updated on your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/345717/christofer-eliasson?tab=accounts), however.

Anyways, the accounts section of the profile is cached, **unless** you're on the site where you actually have that reputation; then it shows your current reputation on that site. That account will *eventually* update, but I can't say how long that will be. Usually if you actually do something on the site (reputation related), it will update faster.